# How to understand a equivalent about the concept of a twisted associative algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, associativity

I am now reading the book ``Algebraic Operads'' written by Murray R. Bremner and Vladimir Dotsenko. In this book,
on page 114-115, 
Definition Let $S_n$ be a permutation group. A twisted associative algebra is a nonnegatively graded associative algebra $A=\oplus_{n\geq0}A(n)$ for each graded component $A(n)$ is a right $S_n$-module, and each product map

$$\mu_{n_1, n_2}:A(n_1) \otimes A(n_2)\rightarrow A(n_1+n_2)$$

is a morphism of $S_{n_1} \times S_{n_2}$-modules.

The author said the map $$A(n_1) \otimes A(n_2)\rightarrow A(n_1+n_2)$$

is a morphism of $S_{n_1} \times S_{n_2}$-modules is equivalent to saying that

[image]
where $\text{sh }(n_1, n_2)$ is the $(n_1, n_2)$-shuffle, $p$ is the canonical projection and $f$ is a symmetric group action.

I don't understand this equivalent completely and who can help me ? I also don't know why my tex code is not showed here correctly.

Comment: More generally: Let $K$ be a commutative ring. Let $B$ be a $K$-algebra, and let $A$ be a $K$-subalgebra of $B$. (My $A$ is not your $A$.) Let $M$ and $N$ be two right $B$-modules. Let $f : N \otimes_K B \to N$ be the right action of $B$ on $N$, written as a $K$-linear map. Let $h$ be a $K$-linear map from $M$ to $N$. Then, $h$ is an $A$-module homomorphism if and only if the $K$-linear map $f \circ \left(h \otimes \operatorname{id}\right) : M \otimes_K B \to N$ (which sends each $m \otimes b$ to $h\left(m\right) b$) factors through the canonical projection $M \otimes_K B \to M \otimes_A B$.

Comment: To get your claim from this fact, set $K = \mathbb{F}$, $B = \mathbb{F}S_{n_1+n_2}$, $A = \mathbb{F}S_{n_1} \times S_{n_2}$, $M = A\left(n_1\right)\otimes A\left(n_2\right)$, $N = A\left(n_1+n_2\right)$ and $h = \mu_{n_1, n_2}$. (I suspect that your source uses a different convention for the order of composition of maps, or else one of us is wrong.)

Comment: Thank you very much, it is my fault. You  are right.

Comment: @darij grinberg, thank you for you useful comment. Can you give me some  details? I am so sorry I don't know this well-known result. Forgive me.

Comment: You can easily prove the general result. The map $f \circ \left(h \otimes \operatorname{id}\right)$ factors through the projection I mentioned if and only if it sends all elements of the form $m \otimes ab - ma \otimes b$ (with $m \in M$, $a \in A$ and $b \in B$) to $0$ (because these elements span the kernel of the projection). But this boils down to $h\left(m\right)ab = h\left(ma\right) b$.